# Advance Import Addon of Newsletter plugin not visible

Tags: wordpress, newsletter

I'm using Wordpress to build my website, I've used the most popular plugin called Newsletter. I'm using it's free version for now. This plugin provides an option to import CSV files, to perform import function I need Advance Import Addon and it's free but I'm not able to see it even after installing it. I've already followed the official newsletter documentation and video tutorial. Below is the video tutorial screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6XiC.png)
Here is my dashboard screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zylvi.png)
Please let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: there's a broken link in the plugin's documentation page, I was able to retrieve an archived copy, please che if it is useful: https://web.archive.org/web/20170719034431/https://www.thenewsletterplugin.com/documentation/install-extensions

Comment: Did you try to debug? https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/